# javascript sorting an array of objects that is used using push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, push

I have this code as follows. I expected that the differences array to be sorted, but when I inspect with Chrome, differences array is the same before and after sort. Please could any one help by pointing out what is wrong in my code and why sort method is not working. It looks like it has to do with the way the array is created (using push) but not sure what is wrong there.

```
var differences = [];

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var myObj = {
        lat      : locations[i].lat,
        lng      : locations[i].lng,
        distance : locations[i].lng
    };

    differences.push(myObj);
}

function compare(a, b) {
   if (a.distance < b.distance)
       return -1;

   if (a.distance > b.distance)
       return 1;

   return 0;
}

console.log(differences);
differences.sort(compare);
console.log(differences);
```

Comment: It's probably just chrome being proactive and showing you the same object in both logs. In your first log, do this `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(differences)));`

Comment: Also, Sort is not really a stable method when used on numbers as the sort method sorts using Unicode. So as example, var nums = [2, 10]; 
nums.sort();  will output 10, 2 not 2, 10 because in unicode, 10 comes before 2 in unicode point order. I would recommend against using Sort on numerics.

Comment: @Korgrue The OP is using a custom compare function. Your argument doesn't apply.

Comment: His compare function returns a number - which is pushed to and returned in-place in the array. The sort method is still doing work on numbers - the result of which is unstable.

Comment: @Korgrue What a silly argument. You're arguing you shouldn't use sort to compare -1, 0 and 1 because it doesn't correctly sort 10 and 2. The compare function in this question is literally the exact method recommended by the MDN documentation page for Array.prototype.sort() and it works perfectly well when used in this manner.

Comment: Its more than just 10 and 2. 10 and 2 is an example. 10 and 3 or 20 and 3 or even 40 and 5 would result in an incorrect sort. I don't consider not using a method that is likely to produce unexpected results a silly argument.

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome's console doesn't convert an Object to a string when you output the Object. Instead, it displays the actual contents of the Object, which are updated if the Object changes afterward.

To demonstrate this, open a console and enter the following lines:

```
var obj = {};
console.log(obj);
obj.helloWorld = "Hi there";
```

By expanding `obj` you can see that the "helloWorld" property is defined for it in the output even though you added it after you logged it to the console.

This means your sort function is working fine. If you want to see the difference before and after, you can clone the object when you log it:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(differences)));
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Another thing that I noticed is that when I log the differences array (before or after sorting) it returns (in Chrome console) an Array like this [] that when I click it expands in the form 0:Object 1:Object etc where which object holds value for the respective properties. When I try to log differences[0] or differences[1] it returns undefined, which looks weird as differences is an array. Not sure what cause this behaviour

Comment: @altin What didn't work? Logging the array before and after the sort didn't show that it had changed?

Comment: I'm not able to see any of the objects in the array. In both cases it returns an empty array.

Comment: Then I think something important is missing from your question. What is locations.length before your for loop?

Comment: I have created locations like an array and populated with data fetched from an endpoint using Ajax. As I mentioned above I am able to log differences array, but get an undefined when I try to log any of its objects like differences[0].

Comment: @altin There's clearly not enough information in your question to get an answer that is satisfactory for you. I suggest you update your question to make it more clear how to reproduce your problem. I suggest you initialize `location` with the contents it is receiving from AJAX so that we can run your code and see why it's not doing what you expect.